# Azure Developer Portal: How to update to new version

Tags: azure, ibm-api-management

I know this question may sound silly. I would like to selfhost the developer portal. I am concerned about future updates/versions. How do you update to a new version. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Are you talking about the **Azure Portal**, or the **APIM Management Portal**? They are different things. Your question title says "Azure Portal", and your question does nothing to disambiguate that. The only reason we can even guess that you're talking about APIM is because of the tag. Please update your question to clarify what you'd like to self-host.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/developer-portal-self-host

Updating the portal requires to pull and integrate the changes from the github repo into your customized portal code (if you changed it).

Comment: Thanks,  just what I assumed. Was not sure though.